# Process.Start an exe file on an network share as another user

Tags: c#, exe, network-share

I need to run an exe file that is located on an network drive in my domain. The drive is successfully attached to my PC as "M:\", but I know that Process.Start( string , string...) need to have URL paths to files when staring processes located on network share.

This is my code:

```
                string user = "user";
                string password = "Qwerty1";
                string domain = "nwtraderds";
                string open = "file://myshare\dir1\dir2\dir3\test.exe";

                string PwString = password;

                char[] PasswordChars = PwString.ToCharArray();
                SecureString Password = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in PasswordChars)
                    Password.AppendChar(c);

                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(open, user, Password, domain);
```

The funny thing is that:

```
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(open);
```

Works fine.
I have run out of ideas, could someone help me please?

Comment: This may be a stupid question but have you tried `\\myshare\dir1\dir2\dir3\test.exe` instead of `file://myshare\dir1\dir2\dir3\test.exe`?

Comment: @Eben Roux Seriously, I don't know what to say. WORKS LIKE A BLAST !
I'm quite sure I tried this but I must have had some wrong directories in the whole path.
The msdn site for Process.Start Method (String, String, SecureString, String) [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxf2saat.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while a network share is already mounted then Windows won't accept accessing it from the same desktop with a different user - you can even try that yourself: just mount it with user1 and then try to mount the same share a second time (in parallel) with a different user (user2) while it is still mounted (same machine, same windows explorer!).

UPDATE:

This `file://myshare\dir1\dir2\dir3\test.exe` won't work !

You either use `\\myserver\myshare\dir1\dir2\dir3\test.exe` (not sure if this works!) OR you use the drive letter `M:\\dir1\dir2\dir3\test.exe` !

Comment: going with this idea, if I would input into user, Password and domain variables, my real credentials it should work ? I tried this and it still shows "The system cannot find the file specified".

Comment: yes thanks, Eben Roux helped me with the same result :) Thanks to both of you for the help, cheers.
I got confused because MSDN says:
"When the executable file is located on a remote drive, you must identify the network share by using a uniform resource identifier (URI), not a linked drive letter."