# The Directory Name is Invalid, mapped drives & username

Tags: c#

I have an application, it first maps a network drive using `credentials` entered by a user.  The drives successfully map, however when it tries to run a program from `Process.Start()`. I get Directory Name is invalid.

From my research I've read to put the working directory for when using a `username/password` in the `StartInfo`.  However this doesn't work.  The working directory is a mapped drive.  Before this starts I do a if `(File.exists(w:\folder\filename)`..Process.start....

I tried to hardcode the working directory to `C:\` but it still failed as it stated it could not find the file.

So when running the `Process.Start` as another user you cannot use a network path, even though that path was mapped by the same account?  Am I forced to download the app locally so the Process.Start can work properly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your problem. I can't understand clearly

Comment: Could you please add some code to show the way you are trying to start the process? And have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189170/process-start-an-exe-file-on-an-network-share-as-another-user... could be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, network shares are a per user token. Running a process as another user (or as the same user in a elevated state) causes a new user token to be created and therefor all active shares are "unmapped" from the perspective of the new process.

You have a few options. The first thing I would try using is use the full UNC path instead of a mapped network drive letter. It may just work if you try that (the new user you are running as will need permissions to connect to the share)

If you are forced to use a drive letter instead of a UNC path then write a small loader program that you launch as the new user, [have that map the network drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803637/connecting-to-a-network-drive-programmatically-and-caching-credentials) in the context of the new user token, then start up your program that relies on the drive.

---

P.S.) Using `C:\` did not work as the working directly likely because `C:\` is a protected folder that only administrators can write files to. If you created a sub folder `C:\MyTestFolder\` and set the proper permissions on it I bet it would have worked.

Comment: Thanks!  I was able to revert to using just the UNC.  I had another application which did the same thing and in there I was using the UNC and not a mapped drive.  Appreciate the explaination and confirmation.